# Can we export/convert equivalent CQLs from Java code that uses Cassandra Java driver?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am new to Cassandra. I am going to use Java driver for Cassandra in my project to access Cassandra functions rather than CQL. But the requirements of the project also include a full set of the CQL instructions identical to the function of the Java program. Can we export the equivalent CQL instructions from the Java program?

Thank you

Comment: what version of Java driver are you using & what components? Java driver also communicates with Cassandra via CQL, but sometimes it's hidden behind builders or mapper...

Comment: I haven't written yet. I am trying to find a good practice and I can use any version of Java driver. I don't know what you meant about components. The functions should be mainly about creating keyspace, table, column, super column, CURD, etc. Thx.

Comment: In this case, just extract strings from your program - driver works with CQL itself

Comment: To this example code 

`Clock clock = new Clock(System.nanoTime());
Column nameCol = new Column("name".getBytes(UTF8), 
ANAME.getBytes("UTF-8"), clock);
`, apparently, it is not simply extracting strings.

Comment: I recommend just start with going through java driver documentation to understand how it works

Comment: @AlexOtt, thx. Is there any log from `session.execute` and similar APIs? So that I can get CQLs that triggered by the program from the log.

Comment: Yes, but it may depend on version of driver - that’s why I asked about it...

Comment: The example code you pasted looks like Thrift, which is an old, deprecated interface to Cassandra. The modern Java driver works very similarly to a JDBC driver, where you explicitly provide CQL statements and bind variables to that.  There is no direct equivalent between Thrift and CQL as they are two separate interfaces with different data models.  Whenever you find Cassandra information on the Web, pay attention to the date it was written and the version it targets. If it's older than 2013 or so, or targets Cassandra prior to 2.0, it's probably so out of date that it's useless.

Comment: Thank you @J.B.Langston for you clarifying. So the solution sounds like, in new versions, people can extract CQLs from the strings from the Java code. Is there any other graceful approaches Cassandra provides in new versions?

As you said Thrift(The OO style driver) is out of date, but still many people like me prefer to code in this way.

Comment: The Java driver has a [query builder](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/query_builder/) that you can use to construct queries programmatically.  There are also ORMs such as [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-cassandra) that support Cassandra.  I personally don't have experience with Spring Data but I would caution any user of an ORM to make sure their underlying CQL data model used by the ORM is designed according to Cassandra data modeling best practices.

Comment: @J.B.Langston, then I would say the link 'query builder' you shared is exactly what I wanted to ask from my example. How can we extract cql instructions from code with query builder? Say the example from the line '
Select query = selectFrom("system", "local").column("release_version"); // SELECT release_version FROM system.local
  SimpleStatement statement = query.build();
  ResultSet rs = session.execute(statement);
'
How can we get the cql from 'statement'? Thanks.

Comment: To get the CQL statement, you can call getQueryString() on the SimpleQuery object returned by the query builder's build() function.  Since you have indicated this is the info you are looking for, I will write up an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java driver has a [query builder](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/query_builder/) that you can use to construct queries programmatically. To get the equivalent CQL statement, you can call [getQueryString](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/SimpleStatement.html#getQueryString--)() on the SimpleStatement object returned by the query builder's build() function.